# Custom Mode for Ace.js causes error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'lastIndex' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, customization, cloud9-ide

I'm creating a web application that will require users to be able to write code in my custom scripting language that is currently in development.  I've used [Cloud9's Ace editor](http://ace.c9.io/) in projects before.  Since I'm used to Ace and know quite a bit about how to implement it, I decided it'd be a perfect fit to fulfill my needs for my script editor.  However, in order to use a custom scripting language, I needed to create a custom Mode for Ace to use.  Here is my mode, which is stored in a file in the ace_editor directory (same directory as ace.js is in):

```
ace.define('ace/mode/customscript', function (require, exports, module) {

    var oop = require("ace/lib/oop");
    var TextMode = require("./text").Mode;
    var Tokenizer = require("ace/tokenizer").Tokenizer;
    this.HighlightRules = require("ace/mode/customscript_highlight_rules").CustomScriptHighlightRules;

    var Mode = function () {
        this.$tokenizer = new Tokenizer(new HighlightRules().getRules());
    };
    oop.inherits(Mode, TextMode);

    exports.Mode = Mode;
});

ace.define('ace/mode/customscript_highlight_rules', function (require, exports, module) {

    var oop = require("ace/lib/oop");
    var TextHighlightRules = require("./text_highlight_rules").TextHighlightRules;
    /*var keywords = [
        "null",
        "new",
        "task",
        "end",
        "if",
        "else",
        "elseif",
        "and",
        "or",
        "not",
        "then",
        "for",
        "loop",
        "while",
        "times",
        "print",
        "use",
        "use_csharp",
        "extend",
        "as",
        "return",
        "continue",
        "my"
    ];
    var keywordsRegex = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
        keywordsRegex = keywordsRegex + keywords[i] + "|";
    }
    keywordsRegex = keywordsRegex.substr(0, keywordsRegex.length - 1);*/

    var CustomScriptHighlightRules = function () {

        this.createKeywordMapper({
            "variable.language": "this",
            "keyword":
                "new task end if else elseif and or not then for loop while times print use use_csharp extend as return continue my",
            "constant.language":
                "true false null"
        }, "text", true, " ");

        this.$rules = {
            "no_regex": [
                {
                    token: "comment",
                    regex: "(->)(.|[\r\n])*(<-)"
                },
                {
                    token: "comment",
                    regex: "--([^\n].*)"
                },
                {
                    token: "string",
                    regex: "(\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\")"
                },
                {
                    token: "numbers",
                    regex: "(\d)?[.]*(\d)*"
                },
                {
                    token: "booleans",
                    regex: "true|false"
                }
            ]
        };

    };

    oop.inherits(CustomScriptHighlightRules, TextHighlightRules);

    exports.CustomScriptHighlightRules = CustomScriptHighlightRules;
});
```

And here is the code I'm using to test the editor:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CustomScript Editor</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="syntax_editor" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">task idk()
    alert("hi")
end</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $().ready(function () {
                var editor = ace.edit("syntax_editor");
                editor.setTheme("ace/theme/twilight");
                editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/customscript");
                editor.getSession().setUseWrapMode(false);
                editor.getSession().setUseSoftTabs(true);
                editor.getSession().setTabSize(4);
                editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
                editor.setFadeFoldWidgets(false);
                document.getElementById("syntax_editor").style.fontSize = 20 + 'px';
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that I'm getting an error from Ace when I load the page that reads:

```
Uncaught TypeError: cannot set property 'lastIndex' of undefined
```

I am using Ace's latest src_noconflict library from GitHub.  What am I doing wrong in my custom mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `"start"` state is missing in your `CustomScriptHighlightRules`
change

```
    this.$rules = {
        "no_regex": [
```

to

```
    this.$rules = {
        "start": [
```